# Изменить шрифт заголовка с помощью кнопок переключателей

Tags: javascript, html

Есть три переключателя:

```
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font1" name="Rupster">
    <label for="font1"><span></span>Rupster</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font2" name="Arial">
    <label for="font2"><span></span>Arial</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font3" name="Acquest">
    <label for="font3"><span></span>Acquest</label>
</div>
```

Есть заголовок, которому нужно изменить шрифт с помощью выбора переключателей:

```
<div class="output_empr_block">
    <h3 id="output_client_text">Текст</h3>
</div>
```

Вопрос: как с помощью JS реализовать смену шрифтов посредством нажатия на переключатели?

Answer (score 2):

Во первых радиокнопки надо обьеденить в группу, дав им всем одно название, во вторых, название шрифта выносим в атрибут `value`. Далее вешаем на каждый радио батон ивентхэндлер на клик, и просто достаем `value` и делаем с ним что хотим :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('#output_client_text').style.fontFamily = this.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="output_empr_block">
  <h3 id="output_client_text">Текст</h3>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font1" name="qwerty" value="Rupster">
  <label for="font1"><span></span>Rupster</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font2" name="qwerty" value="Arial">
  <label for="font2"><span></span>Arial</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font3" name="qwerty" value="Acquest">
  <label for="font3"><span></span>Acquest</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getValueSetFont(fontFamily)
{
    document.getElementById('output_client_text').style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
}
```

```html
<div class="output_empr_block">
    <h3 id="output_client_text">Текст</h3>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font1" name="font_changer" onclick="getValueSetFont('Courier')">
    <label for="font1"><span></span>Rupster</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font2" name="font_changer" onclick="getValueSetFont('Arial')">
    <label for="font2"><span></span>Arial</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font3" name="font_changer" onclick="getValueSetFont('Tahoma')">
    <label for="font3"><span></span>Acquest</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function setClass(el) {
  document.querySelector('#output_client_text').className = el.getAttribute('font');
}
```

```css
h3.Arial {
  font-family: Arial
}

h3.Acquest {
  font-family: Acquest
}

h3.Rupster {
  font-family: Rupster
}
```

```html
<div class="radio" font="Rupster" onmousedown="setClass(this)">
  <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font1" name="a">
  <label for="font1"><span></span>Rupster</label>
</div>

<div class="radio" font="Arial" onmousedown="setClass(this)">
  <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font2" name="a">
  <label for="font2"><span></span>Arial</label>
</div>

<div class="radio" font="Acquest" onmousedown="setClass(this)">
  <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font3" name="a">
  <label for="font3"><span></span>Acquest</label>
</div>

<div class="output_empr_block">
  <h3 id="output_client_text">Текст</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать такой вариант решения, где:

- инициализируется текущее состояния чекбоксов на наличие уже
  существующего атрибута checked;
- список возможных классов для
  использования, которые описываются в соответствующем объекте (совершенно не требуется прописывать инлайново шрифты в тегах);
- контейнер, к которому применяются классы, не завист от количества уже существующих в нем классов, т.е. существующие не затираются;
- код универсальный и может применяться не только к инпутам. Может
  поддерживать и другие eventListner'ы.

**Работает в Chrome/Mozilla/Edge.**

```js
const radios = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.radio_check'));
const output = document.querySelector('.output_empr_block');

//Здесь мы добавляем перечень с нашими классами, где свойству соответствует идентификатор input'a с атрибутом data-name, которое мы будем получать при соответствующих событиях
const classObject = {
 'Arial': 'arial',
 'Acquest': 'acquest',
 'Rupster': 'rupster'
}

//Проверяем состояние чекбоксов, если необходимый чекбокс уже активирован - сразу инициализируем соответствующий стиль для контейнера
const _getInitialCheckedState = (selectedFont) => {
 radios.filter(item => { 
   if(item.checked) {
   selectedFont = item.getAttribute('data-name')
   } 
  })
 return selectedFont;
}

//Функция, где мы проверяем data-name значения с "классами", которые указаны в classObject
const _requestFontupdate = (requestedData = _getInitialCheckedState()) => {
 for(let value in classObject) {
  if(requestedData === value) {
   output.classList.add(classObject[value])
  } else {
   output.classList.remove(classObject[value]);
  }
 }
}
//При изменении состояния наших чекбоксов запускаем соотвутствующую функцию.
radios.forEach(function(item){
 item.addEventListener('change', () => {
   _requestFontupdate(item.getAttribute('data-name'));
 })
})
_requestFontupdate();
```

```css
.arial {
 color: red;
}
.acquest {
 color: green;
}
.rupster {
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font2" data-name="Arial" name='radioset' checked>
    <label for="font2"><span></span>Arial</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font1" data-name="Rupster" name='radioset'>
    <label for="font1"><span></span>Rupster</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio_check" id="font3" data-name="Acquest" name='radioset'>
    <label for="font3"><span></span>Acquest</label>
</div>
<div class="output_empr_block">
    <h3 id="output_client_text">Текст</h3>
</div>
```